# What is the relation sense of Taylor formula in optimization?

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion

In the course, we do a lot of examples about optimization using Taylor method, but I notice that if we have function like:
$f(x) =  \alpha \times x^2 + \beta\times y^2 + \sigma \times xy + \gamma \times x + \phi \times y + \xi$
without determine the Hessian, I can ensure that Taylor formula will be:
$f(a+h)-f(a)= \alpha \times x^2 + \beta\times y^2 + \sigma \times xy$
with a a critic point.
So it is always true? if yes what is the rule of Hessian here? I am really confused

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Consider that many users in this forum won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well, you are asking why the Taylor polynomial of your function is the function itself. This happens because $f$ is by itself a polynomial. In fact, a function is equal to its (finite) Taylor polynomial iff it is a polynomial.

Comment: So for every polynomial function, i don't need really to apply Taylor formula because , i will find the function itself?

Comment: Yes, that's it.